# Need explanation for a setState problem in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I want to manage my state as whenever I click the button , the state should add 'monkey' to previous state. My initial state value is null. If I set state as **text: prevState.text+'monkey'** that's okey.But if I use += instead of semicolon **prevState.text+='monkey'**,'monkey' appears twice when I click the button.Here is my component.I want to know the explanation why monkey appears twice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state={
    text:''
  }
  onClickHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prevState=>prevState.text+='monkey'

    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
          press
        </button>
        {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;`
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` takes either a new state object as an argument, or a function which returns an object.  You're not returning an object, but rather the value of `state.monkey` + 'monkey'.  Try this:

```js
onClickHandler = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    text: prevState.text += 'monkey'
  }))
}
```

Keep in mind, if prevstate.text is already 'monkey', you'll end up with 'monkey' += 'monkey', which is indeed 'monkeymonkey'.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you are not returning an object to the state but rather a string, when you use `setState(prevState=>...)`, you are passing in the state as a argument.

```
prevState.text += 'monkey'
```

is the same as

```
prevState.text = prevState.text + 'monkey'
```

which is mutating the state directly, leading to your issue. You are essentially changing `this.state.text` directly to 'monkey' and then your `setState` function, which is async, finishes and is adding `monkey` to the end of that, thus 'monkeymonkey'

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Seth Lutske's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67610739/1681154) You can simplify it further like

```
onClickHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    text: this.state.text + 'monkey'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the function pattern. Just lose the '=' sign.

```
 onClickHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prevState=> { 
    return { text : prevState.text + 'monkey' }
    });
  }
```